# Bing Maps v8 - infobox anchoring behavior has changed

Tags: bing-maps

In Bing Maps v8, I'm seeing different behavior between the release and frozen branches with regard to the anchoring of infoboxes.

I have icons on the map, which I click on to open an infobox at the location I clicked.

```
hhInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { visible: false, showPointer: false });
....
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'click', showHouseholdInfobox);
...
function showHouseholdInfobox(e) {
    ....
    hhInfobox.setOptions({
        visible: true, title: e.target.hhTitle, description: targetHtml
    });
    hhInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
}
```

When I click on this icon (i.stack.imgur.com/nam9Q.png),

the infobox appears here in the frozen branch (i.stack.imgur.com/1fSDi.png) (a bit south of the top left of infobox is anchored to click location)

but here in the release branch (i.stack.imgur.com/mLQ3k.png) (bottom left of infobox is anchored to click location).

The release branch behavior is a problem because the infobox might be 2100 pixels high, and when I set a max-height of 600, the top stays fixed while the bottom moves up 1500 pixels, and the user has to scroll up a few pages to find the infobox.

So my questions are (1) is this new behavior a bug or a feature? And (2) if it's a feature, what is the best way to anchor the top left of the infobox to the click location?

Using setHtmlContent might be the answer. (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712643.aspx) says "when custom HTML is used to represent the infobox, the infobox is anchored at the bottom-left corner," but I found that it anchors at the top left corner (i.stack.imgur.com/bvc7l.png), which is what I want, though I'd have to play with the HTML.

If this is a bug that will be fixed soon then I'll do nothing. Otherwise I'll probably use setHtmlContent unless someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release and frozen branches are very different at this point. The release branch is updated monthly and the frozen branch is updated once a year. Most companies should and do use the main release branch. The frozen branch is primarily for mission critical apps such as 911 call centers or emergency services scenarios who want a slower release cycle, as releases are when outages are most likely to occur, knowing that new features and bug fixes won't be fixed in that version for a long time. The frozen branch was last updated when V8 was released in June. A lot of new features and bug fixes have been released since then which are not in the frozen branch.

For completeness, the experimental branch is updated several times a day. More documentation on the branching system in Bing Maps V8 can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712554.aspx

As for positioning the infobox, you can control the anchor using the anchor property of the infobox class. By default, when the pointer is hidden and no anchor is provided, the infobox anchors its bottom left corner to the location. I've tried various content and maxHeight values and it always rendered correctly.

Comment: Thanks. We do use the release branch; I was just trying to compare the current behavior with an earlier version, to verify that this was a recent change. Setting the anchor did not work for me, so maybe I'm doing something that's interfering with that. Anyway, setHtmlContent did work for me.